# Let $f : R → R$ be a continuous decreasing function. Prove that the system $x = f(y),$ $y = f(z),$ $z = f(x)$ has a unique solution.

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f : R → R$ be a continuous decreasing function. Prove that the system

$$x = f(y),$$

$$y = f(z),$$

$$z = f(x)$$
has a unique solution.

Here using the intermediate value theorem, it can clearly be seen that when

$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to -\infty}}f(x)-x$ = $\infty $

& $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty}}f(x)-x$ = -$\infty $  &

we get some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = x_0$
But how or why does that imply that $x_0 = x = y = z$

Comment: Note that any such solution $(x, y, z)$ will satisfy $x=f^{\circ 3}(x)$ and that $f^{\circ 3}(\cdot)$ is decreasing. Using this, show that $x\neq x_0$ leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$h(x) = f(f(f(x)))$ is strictly decreasing with $\lim_{x \to -\infty}h(x)-x = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}h(x)-x = -\infty$, so that $h$ has a unique fixed point $a$.

Then $(x, y, z) = (f(f(a)), f(a), a)$ satisfies
$$ \tag{*}
x=f(y) \, , \, y=f(z) \, , \, z=f(x)  \, .
$$

If $(x, y, z)$ is any solution of $(*)$ then $h(x) = x$, $h(y) = y$ and $h(z) = z$ implies $x=y=z= a$ because the fixed point of $h$ is unique.

Comment: You latter part is clear but what was the motivation behind considering $f(f(f(x)))$ ?

Comment: @mathx: The given condition implies that $x$, $y$, $z$ are all fixed points of the third iterate of $f$, which is strictly decreasing.

Comment: OK. Well explained.

Comment: @mathx: This also demonstrates that $f$ and $h = f \circ f \circ f$ have the *same* fixed point.